# И - союз или частица?

Tags: морфология

Скажите, пожалуйста, какой частью речи является "и" в данном предложении:

> Да быть такого не может! Чтобы Матвей — и не поздоровался!

Answer (score 1):

[***И**, частица.*](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%B8&all=x)

> **1.** Усиливает значение слова, перед которым стоит, для выделения, подчёркивания его. ***И** какая же ты стала слезливая.* **2.**
> Соответствует по зн. частицам: тоже, также. *Будет **и** на нашей
> улице праздник* (Погов.). *Все говорят: нет правды на земле. Но правды
> нет — **и** выше* (Пушкин). **3.** Соответствует по зн. частице даже.
> *Отец **и** не подозревал о переживаниях сына.*

*Быть такого не может! Чтобы Матвей — **да** не поздоровался!*

Comment: Сомневаюсь насчет кузнецовского (я его сразу распознал!) отнесения примеров с "улицей" и Пушкиным к случаю "частицы".  В обоих примерах больше похоже на _союз_ (не только на чьей-то, но и на нашей; не только на земле, но и выше). В нашем случае тоже видится союз, поскольку смысл в противопоставлении "Матвея" и (=да) "не поздороваться" как двух "вещей несовместных".

Comment: Сашко, работа союза - соединять, частицы - усиливать или служить синонимом другой частицы.

Comment: @Alex_ander интересное наблюдение. Теперь этимологически понятно, почему частицей является именно союз "и", а не что-то другое. Предлагаю компромис: "частица-союз"